# Mingle, transitive - meaning in an example: His soul mingled in the third black kiss of Death

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, archaic-language

In a story by H. Kuttner and R. Bloch, there is the following line:

> His soul mingled in the third black kiss of Death.

No dictionary entries I found make sense to me. I guess the meaning is not "to mix" as there I would be another preposition. Something "dissolve" would make sense but I think that is not the intended meaning.
Thanks for help!

Comment: I learned. around 1960 or so, not to expect good writing from Henry Kuttner or Robert Bloch.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, and how would you then understand the sentence, please?

Comment: With no preposition, usually the object is understood already.  It sounds like his soul is mixing in with the "kiss" in some sense.  But if you are at a party, saying, "I mingled." just means you mingle with the crowd of people there.

Comment: Although perhaps there are other souls there, in the kiss, somehow.  Maybe it is a place, like Hades, or something, and it is all full of souls.

Comment: This is impossible to answer unless someone here is familiar with the story (which story?). Can you give us more context?

Comment: Death is being treated as both a person and an experience here -- it is both intimate and surrounding; that is how the character's soul could mingle (that is, be among as a person is among others in a crowd) in the surrounding nature of death.

Comment: This is literature and thus, no amount of dictionary definition will really get you where the author intends for you to be. That being said, without any of the story’s context, literary interpretation is impossible.